# Babel - Transpile code and minify it

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Right now in my Node application i use Babel to transpile ES6 syntax with this command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel src/ -d bin/
```

With this, babel compile my code and this can be executed from `node`

Because my application will be installed in different machines, i would like to "minify" it, or create a sort of release where source code is not accessible.

I have many directories in `src/` and this will maintain the same order in `bin/`, this will be ok, i just would like that the "binary" code produced is minified or in some way "crypted" and not human redeable.

I've search a lot of it and (if i have understand well) `babel` dont have this options.

How i can do that ?

Comment: You might consider using [webpack](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I) which encompasses babel and does a lot more as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean `compact` option? ( default is "auto" )

> Do not include superfluous whitespace characters and line terminators. When set > to "auto" compact is set to true on input sizes of >100KB.

But in fact it's not task for babel. You can use additional tool ( like [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) ) for minifying / obfuscation code